# Magento 2 static files are not being loaded after enabling HTTPS

Tags: magento2, ssl

I set Secure Base URL to https://magento22.local , did setup:upgrade
[image: settings]
But now it tries to load all static content through http and chrome gives error "mixed content", so no styles or script are loaded.

[image: result]
I tried clearing everything - cache, static files folder, reloading server, enabling production mode - nothing helps.

What's the problem? Why Magento doesn't use HTTPS URLs?

"Use Secure URLs on Storefront" setting doesn't change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't finished local SSL setup with adding this to my whosts file:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

   ...

SSLEngine on

SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key

<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Because of that magento's isSecure() method was returning false (it checks values in $_SERVER array - HTTPS and PORT - not just checks the requested URL) and Magento used settings from the Unsecure section.

Answer (score 1):

here you go:

bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url="https://domain.com/" --base-url-secure="https://domain.com/" --use-secure=1 --use-secure-admin=1
bin/magento cache:flush

change domain.com to your domain.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute below command and try it in magento root directory.

> $ rm -rf pub/static/frontend/* pub/static/adminhtml/* var/cache/ generated/* var/page_cache/ var/view_preprocessed/ var/composer_home 
>   $ php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

In above code `$ rm -rf` command delete your `pub/static` & `var/cache`.

For more reference you can check [This link](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/JS-amp-amp-CSS-not-loading-After-Enable-SSL/m-p/105320#M6438)

---

**Edit :**

Make sure your configuration looks like this:

> Stores > Configuration > General > Web:

Base URLs:

- Base URL: https://www.yourdomain.com/
- Base Link URL: [X] Use system
  value (will be the same as base URL)

Base URLs (Secure):

- Secure Base URL: https://www.yourdomain.com/
- Secure Base Link URL: {{secure_base_url}}
- Use Secure URLs on Storefront: Yes
- Use Secure URLs in Admin: Yes
- Enable HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS): Yes
- Upgrade Insecure Requests: Yes

---

**Edit :**

It might be a chance **Static content signing** problem because

Static content signing is a Magento feature that allows you to invalidate the browser cache for static resources. Magento accomplishes this by adding a deployment version to the URL of static files .

The following is an example of a URL signed with a version:

> http://magento2.com/pub/static/version1475604434/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/images/logo.svg

When you run the command setup:static-content:deploy to deploy static content, Magento automatically changes the deployment version. This changes the URL of the static files and forces the browser to load the new version of the files.

For that you need to change the setting of **Static content signing** under

> Stores > System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Static Files Settings.

Set to **NO**

And then run below command.

> $ rm -rf pub/static/frontend/* pub/static/adminhtml/* var/cache/ generated/* var/page_cache/ var/view_preprocessed/ var/composer_home $ php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Then check it might be work.

For more reference check [DevDocs links](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cache/static-content-signing.html)

I hope it helps!

Comment: Magento still tries to load css and js files with http

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: And you not passed correct URL in `Base URLs:` you misses to pass `s`, you hav to pass `http` to `https`

Comment: Base URL's should be http://, https is only for secure.

Comment: @Audiophile check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install ssl for localhost server?

Try to add it:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Modify section:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to this

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

After that, run command

```
sudo a2enmod ssl

sudo a2ensite default-ssl

sudo a2enmod rewrite

sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Looks like the problem with certificate. Magento's isSecure method returns false when I access site with HTTPS